# Passing variables to new nib loaded for swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UItable on a view controller, from that ViewController is a segue to another view controller which has been set up as kind of a master to show three nibs in a swipe motions.

## Video

I followed this video to create the sliding views: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU

kinda like this:

[image]

I can get the data to pass between the two view controllers but I can't get it to display on any of the nibs.

How do I get the slide across nibs to display the variable that is defined in the master view (one that hols the nibs) controller?

## ViewController2.Swift

```
    let vc0 = vc0(nibName: "vc0", bundle: nil)
    let vc1 = vc1(nibName: "vc1", bundle: nil)
    let vc2 = vc2(nibName: "vc2", bundle: nil)

    // The above are the names of 3 other ViewControllers that were created with Nib Files. This code below, puts those nibs in a slide view.
    
    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1
    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame = frame2
    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    
    
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)
```

From the first view controller to the one holding the nibs I am passing the variable in the prepareForSegue.

If you need to know anything else, just ask :)

## edit 1

The first view controller is called viewcontroller, the second (one that holds the nibs and the code above) is called viewcontroller2:

## ViewController1.Swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if "viewcontroller2Segue" == segue.identifier {
        
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! viewcontroller2;
        vc.passedID = clickedCell
        
        
    }
}
```

on viewcontroller2, I have a variable which gets assigned the data:

```
var passedID = ""
```

Comment: You're are not showing any code regarding the passing of data which seems to be the thrust of your question. Like don't you need to set some properties on vc0, vc1, or vc2? Where are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `let vc2 = vc2(nibName: "vc2", bundle: nil)` instantiates a new instance of vc2, so none of it's properties are set. From the diagram it appears you have a container view controller that is has child view controllers of type vc0, vc1, vc2. It's not clear to me what class segue.destinationViewController, maybe vc2, but either way you need to pass the data between segue.destinationViewController to the vc0, vc1, and vc2 you instantiate. For example:

```
let vc0 = vc0(nibName: "vc0", bundle: nil)
let vc1 = vc1(nibName: "vc1", bundle: nil)
let vc2 = vc2(nibName: "vc2", bundle: nil)

vc0.neededID = self.passedID  //if vc0 needs passedID
vc1.neededID = self.passedID  //if vc1 needs passedID
vc2.neededID = self.passedID  //if vc2 needs passedID
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are no segues between the new loaded nibs, how do I tell xcode to get the data and pass it?

Comment: I updated my answer vc0, vc1, and vc2 need to be subclasses of UIViewControllers with properties that you can set. Those properties can then be set by ViewController2 after they are instantiated.

Comment: you sir I could fall in love with. Thank you